# Moving from Java on Linux to Eclipse/remote system explorer

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

Brief: How to setup a project on a remote server?

I have been trying to work on Java code on a remote server by logging into it using Putty on windows and editing it using a basic text editor. I intend to move to Eclipse/Remote system explorer. I did just that and I could use Eclipse as an editor, but compile on the remote server.

Problem:
1. I am trying to get the features of Eclipse where it suggests me the available methods for a n object; however, I get this error: This compilation unit is not in the build path of a java project"

As I understand, I haven't set it up as a project. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally haven't tried that , but this could be useful to you  :)

http://www.patrickjwaters.com/blog/2011-07-24/how-setup-eclipse-php-pdt-remote-system-explorer-theme-manager-and-drupal-plugins/35